# Multiple memory address in C

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, computer-science

As I understand a byte is comprised of 8 bits or byte and it has an address assign to it my question is if I asked for 2 words  am I getting then 4 different addresses or do I get one address for the whole Word? Any explanation will be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: You're asking about a tricky question.  A word is an array of characters.  You have an address that points at the start, but then each character would have it's own address but the pointer to the char array would point at position 0 still.

Comment: You should be more specific, by showing your code. What does `"if I asked for 2 words"` mean?

Comment: C and C++ count in terms of `char`s not bytes. A `char` can be 7, 8, 9, 16 bits or whatever else, depending on your platform.

Comment: @Chemistpp Is this question asking about words as in the size of the instruction set?

Comment: I'm asking in terms of bits and bytes a Word is 2 bytes I didn't mention anything about chars thanks for your comments though

Comment: @syam Actually, in C a `char` can not be 7 bits. C defines the required minimum range of values for `char` such that a `char` _must_ be at least 8 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make an allocation then the allocation as a whole has an address, and each byte within it also has an address.

The address of the first byte in the allocation is equal to the address of the allocation, and the remaining bytes have consecutive addresses counting up from there.

"Making an allocation" here covers global variables, automatic variables, `new`, `malloc`, anything that assigns memory for a specific use. To use technical jargon, every object in C and in C++ is a series of bytes with consecutive addresses.

If your system uses virtual memory (which approximately everything does), then the addresses are consecutive in *virtual* address space. They need not be consecutive in physical memory, but then the whole point of virtual memory is that you (the programmer) can ignore where things are in physical memory.

Comment: thanks for your clear answer. So if I would to assign something like this `char s[] = "test"` I would get an address for the whole array but also consecutive addresses for `s[0], s[1],s[2],s[4]` right?

Comment: @LeandroVillagran: yes, `s[0]` ... `s[3]` will have values `'t'`, `'e'`, `'s'`, `'t'`, and `s[4]` will have value `0` (it's the nul terminating character). You can also see that `sizeof(s)` is `5`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @Steve Jessop I was really confused but now I understand

Answer (score 2):

What is commonly thought of as the "address" of any object or variable is the address of the *first* (lowest) byte in that variable. So if, you have a variable of type std::uint64_t (8 bytes) a pointer to that variable will be to it's first byte, while the following 7 addresses contain the other 7 bytes. Now, the *order* in which those bytes are stored depends on your implementation (look up little-endian versus big-endian architecture).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks this reinforced the answer from @Steve Jessop and I actually just learned about litte and big endian yesterday. Thanks Limne

Answer (score 0):

In C, all objects except bit-fields are made from one or more bytes:

> C 2011 (N1570) 6.2.6.1 says “Except for bit-fields, objects are composed of contiguous sequences of one or more bytes, the number, order, and encoding of which are either explicitly specified or implementation-defined.”

When you access an object that is composed of multiple bytes, such as an `int` (typically), all of the bytes of the object are accessed for you.

For any object that is natively supported by the processor hardware, there are load and store instructions that take a single address but operate on multiple bytes starting at that address. E.g., there are “load word” instructions that load four bytes starting from the address of one byte. (There is no standard for how big a “word” is; it varies from one computer architecture to another.) For objects that are created by the C implementation (such as struct objects with several members), the C implementation must use multiple instructions to load and store all of the parts of the object.

Answer (score -1):

there missed a s[3],which is 't'.and s[4],it is '\0'